# in my program if statement doesnt return any object in django else statement is executing

Tags: python, django

```
class wenket(View):
    print "qqqqqqqqqqqqqq"
    def get(self,request):
        number1=request.GET['number']
        print"bbbbbbbbbb",number1
        return self.primenumbdef(number1)
    def primenumbdef(self,number1):
        print"aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"
        if number1==100:
            return HttpResponse(d({"value of number is 100":number1}))
        else:
           return HttpResponse(d({"value of number is not 100": number1}))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `request.GET['number']` you are getting from the `request` object is a string (`'100'`). You should consider cast it to `int` and then compare it with `100`. That is,

```
def get(self,request):
    number1 = int(request.GET['number'])
    print"bbbbbbbbbb", number1
    return self.primenumbdef(number1)
```

or if you want to catch edge cases where the `number` may be not a number, try this:

```
def get(self,request):
    number1 = request.GET['number']
    try:
        number1 = int(number1)
    except ValueError as e:
        # handle case here
    else:
        print"bbbbbbbbbb",number1
        return self.primenumbdef(number1)
```